# Find Total row count of Select Query with Order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following query and I want to count total row count as `@TotalRows`.

```
Declare @TotalRows int

@TotalRows = Count(Select distinct 
                       a.id as apptID, i.Insurancename, InsDtl.Insurenceclassification
                   From 
                       Appointment A    
                   Left Outer join 
                       Insuarancedetails InsDtl WITH (NOLOCK) on InsDtl.AppId  = A.ID
                   Left Outer join 
                       Insurance i WITH (NOLOCK) on i.ID = InsDtl.Insurencepayer
                   order by 
                       apptID, Insurancename)
```

I have tried with `Count(*)` and `Row_Number()` but it's not wotking. It says subquery is not allowed with order by clause.

Comment: Can you tell how how your result should look like

Comment: I want only count and I set that count in one declare variable.

Comment: select  @TotalRows=count(*) from (your query here) T

Comment: @nazark : Sub query does not allow order by. So its not work

Comment: @Hitesh Why you want `order by` when you just need `count`. Remove it from `sub-query`

Comment: @Prdp Its requirement of our query. Here in Question I have post only sample query. Thanks

Comment: Removing `order by` clause doesn't affect records count and thereby doesn't violate your requirements.

Comment: @Arvo Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT
     A.apptID, 
     A.Insurancename, 
     A.Insurenceclassification,
     COUNT(A.TmpColumn) OVER (PARTITION BY A.TmpColumn) AS CountOfRow
FROM
(
    SELECT distinct 
        a.id as apptID, 
        i.Insurancename, 
        InsDtl.Insurenceclassification,
        1 AS TmpColumn
    FROM 
        Appointment A Left Outer join 
        Insuarancedetails InsDtl WITH (NOLOCK) on InsDtl.AppId  = A.ID  Left Outer join 
        Insurance i WITH (NOLOCK) on i.ID = InsDtl.Insurencepayer    
) A
ORDER BY 
    A.apptID,
    A.Insurancename
```

Updated Because question is updated

```
DECLARE @TotalRows INT

SELECT
    @TotalRows = COUNT(A.apptID)
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        a.id as apptID, 
        i.Insurancename, 
        InsDtl.Insurenceclassification
    FROM 
        Appointment A   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        Insuarancedetails InsDtl WITH (NOLOCK) on InsDtl.AppId  = A.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        Insurance i WITH (NOLOCK) on i.ID = InsDtl.Insurencepayer
 ) A
```

Comment: Thanks Hebele for your reply

Answer (score 1):

you can use @@rowcount immediately after the select statement to get affected rows,

```
DECLARE @TotalRows INT

Select distinct a.id as apptID, i.Insurancename, InsDtl.Insurenceclassification
From Appointment A    
  Left Outer join Insuarancedetails InsDtl WITH (NOLOCK) on InsDtl.AppId  = A.ID
  Left Outer join Insurance i WITH (NOLOCK) on i.ID = InsDtl.Insurencepayer
 ORDER BY apptID,Insurancename

SELECT @TotalRows = @@ROWCOUNT
```

Comment: it works fine but I am using @TotalRows in my main query in same Store Procedure So using your query its also display result of above query. Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Distinct implies Group by,so change query to group by   and use count..

```
   select a.id , i.Insurancename, InsDtl.Insurenceclassification,count(*) as cnt
    From Appointment A    
    Left Outer join 
    Insuarancedetails InsDtl WITH (NOLOCK) on InsDtl.AppId  = A.ID
     Left Outer join 
    Insurance i WITH (NOLOCK) on i.ID = InsDtl.Insurencepayer
    group by a.id, i.Insurancename, InsDtl.Insurenceclassification
     ORDER BY apptID,Insurancename
```